# Blocking unwanted users from access another users profile data with function based view in Django

Tags: python, django

I am working with some function-based views in `Django`. I have a custom build decorator named `industry_required` which allows passing by verifying a user is authenticated from an `Industrial` account or not.

I have some functions in `views.py` and their particular URL in `urls.py`. like:

in `urls.py`:

```
path('industryDetails/', views.industryDetails.as_view(), name='industryDetails'),
path('industry_create_report/<int:pk>/', views.industry_create_report, name='industry_create_report'),
```

in `views.py`:

```
@method_decorator(industry_required, name='dispatch')
class industryDetails(DetailView):
    model = Industry
    template_name = 'app/industryDetails.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Industry.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Industry, user=self.request.user)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['inserted_text'] = "inserted text from EmployeeDetails of views.py"
        context['employee_table'] = self.object.employee_set.all()
        return context
    
    
def industry_create_report(request):
    industry_create_report_dict = {
        
    }
    #bla bla....
    return render(request, 'app/industry_create_report.html', industry_create_report_dict)
```

Now my problem is when I use the `DetailView`, I can easily ensure that which user logged in that user can see only his `DetailView` profile by using the method_decorator named `industry_required` and `get_queryset` and `get_object` method.

But when I use the `function-based` view, suppose an `Industrial` account user with `pk=1` can also see the data of `pk=2` with using URL pattern (industry_create_report/2/), which is not desireable.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function based view, you need to fetch the industry using a similiar filter to what you had specified in `industryDetails.get_queryset`.

```
def function_based_view(request, pk):
    industry = get_object_or_404(Industry.objects.filter(user=self.request.user), pk=pk)
```